# Avoiding multiple sub queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update a couple of columns in a table using another record in the same table. Following is the SQL that I came up with but I'm wondering how I can avoid multiple sub queries that will return the same record. I'm working on **Oracle 11gR2**.

```
UPDATE
  IFTBL E
SET
  E.ATT_CREATED = (SELECT A.CREATED FROM ATT A WHERE A.ROW_ID = E.T_ACTIVITYA__RID),
  E.ATT_CREATED_BY = (SELECT B.CREATED_BY FROM ATT B WHERE B.ROW_ID = E.T_ACTIVITYA__RID)
WHERE
  E.IF_ROW_BATCH_NUM = BATCH_NO_IN AND E.IF_ROW_STAT = 'EXPORTED' AND E.ATT_FILE_SRC_TYPE = 'FILE';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Merge.

```
    MERGE INTO IFTBL 
    USING 
    (
      SELECT CREATED,CREATED_BY,ROW_ID 
      FROM ATT 
    ) A ON (A.ROW_ID = IFTBL.T_ACTIVITYA__RID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
        SET 
        IFTBL.ATT_CREATED = A.CREATED, 
        IFTBL.ATT_CREATED_BY = A.CREATED_BY
    WHERE
    IFTBL.IF_ROW_BATCH_NUM = BATCH_NO_IN 
    AND IFTBL.IF_ROW_STAT = 'EXPORTED' 
    AND IFTBL.ATT_FILE_SRC_TYPE = 'FILE'
```

Answer (score 0):

If ROW_ID is primary key in `ATT` and T_ACTIVITYA__RID is foreign key on `IFTBL` with reference to  ROW_ID you may write update (select ...)

```
update (select E.ATT_CREATED, E.ATT_CREATED_BY  
               A.CREATED , A.CREATED_BY 
          from IFTBL E, ATT A 
         where E.T_ACTIVITYA__RID = A.ROW_ID(+)
           AND E.IF_ROW_BATCH_NUM = BATCH_NO_IN 
           AND E.IF_ROW_STAT = 'EXPORTED' 
           AND E.ATT_FILE_SRC_TYPE = 'FILE')
SET ATT_CREATED = CREATED, 
    ATT_CREATED_BY = CREATED_BY ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you could simply do a multi-column update:

```
UPDATE
  IFTBL E
SET
  (E.ATT_CREATED, E.ATT_CREATED_BY) = (SELECT A.CREATED,
                                              A.CREATED_BY
                                       FROM   ATT A
                                       WHERE  A.ROW_ID = E.T_ACTIVITYA__RID)
WHERE
  E.IF_ROW_BATCH_NUM = BATCH_NO_IN
  AND E.IF_ROW_STAT = 'EXPORTED'
  AND E.ATT_FILE_SRC_TYPE = 'FILE';
```